# Convert a string to raw string

Tags: dart

It's easy so declare a raw string

```
String raw = @'\"Hello\"';
```

But how can I convert a existing string to a raw string ?
This can come with file reading or ajax call : I want read the file as a raw string but the `readAsText` method give me a no raw string.
I tryied thing like :

```
String notRaw = '\"Hello\"';
String raw = @raw;
```

But not compiling.
How can I do this?

EDIT : My need is to read the string char by char. So I don't want to read \" as one char " but as two chars \ and "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read a file without interpreting escape characters, then you need to [`readAsBytes`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/continuous/dart_io/File.html#readAsBytes), which will give you a list of characters as integers. You can then detect a backslash and quote as:

```
final int backSlash = @'\'.charCodeAt(0); 
final int quote = @'"'.charCodeAt(0);
```

You then pass the desired substrings to a string constructor:

```
String goodString = new String.fromCharCodes(byteList.getRange(start, end));
```

Answer (score 0):

A raw string literal is still a string. The only difference is that it everything within a raw literal is accepted as-is, i.e. no escape sequences.

For example, in a plain (non-raw) string literal `'a\nb'` represents letter 'a', newline, letter 'b'; in a raw string literal it represents letter 'a', backslash, letter 'n', letter 'b'.

Comment: Yes, that's why I need a raw string. Indeed, I try to parse the string by reading char by char. So when reading \",  instead of reading "  I need read  \ and ".