# What does @ in front of a Dart string mean

Tags: dart

I found some Dart code with @ in front of a string:

```
_specialCharactersInsideCharacterClass = new HashSet.from([@"^", @"-", @"]"]);
```

Found in: [RegExpBuilder.dart](https://github.com/agamia/RegExpBuilder/blob/master/RegExpBuilder.dart)

What is the meaning of the symbol @ in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, a prefix `@` character in front of a string is not valid Dart code. But I can imaging that it is was used to disable escaping and string interpolation [in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978549/convert-a-string-to-raw-string). The linked Dart file is from 2013, so maybe it was created before the prefix `r` was introduced to mark [raw strings](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#strings):

```
_specialCharactersInsideCharacterClass = new HashSet.from([r"^", r"-", r"]"]);
```

In raw strings, string interpolation (using the `$` character) and escaping (for example `\r`) are disabled.